# Why I can't switch my GCC version?

Tags: gcc, caffe

My system environment is:Ubuntu 14.04,I have installed CUDA8.0 and OpenCV3.1,now I want to make my caffe，but it reminds me that the GCC-5.3 version isn't right. So I installed new GCC version and uninstalled all about GCC-5.3,but now  when I try to switch its  version, it doesn't work and it's still GCC-5.3.0. Please see the image. Could anyone solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: GCC 5.3 is far to new for Ubuntu 14.04, have you installed it yourself in a custom location? Is that custom location *in the `$PATH`*?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that. I have checked all the installation files and found there is no GCC-5.3 more, what do you mean for "$PATH"?which path?

Comment: Sorry I've just recognized $PATH means environment variable.

Comment: What about `whereis gcc`??

Comment: I have checked the $PATH, it doesn't include my custom location of GCC-5.3 .

Comment: I  installed GCC-5.3  in "/usr/bin/"

Comment: There is a specific site "askubuntu". Installing anything that is not an ubuntu package in /usr is a bad idea (aim for /usr/local or somewhere under /opt instead). How about upgrading to a newer version of ubuntu if you want newer software?

Comment: Thank you,I will try "askubuntu" ,but if the system upgrades to Ubuntu16.04, all the softwares need to be installed again, that's a little complicated.

Comment: Finally, I choose to rebuild the Ubuntu system and it works.Now it's still Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

After having tried many ways, I finally decided to uninstall all the GCC versions and then install the versions under v5.0. Eventually, it worked.